# wordpress Shorcode

Tags: wordpress, cart, shortcode, custom-pages

I'm using car66 plugin in my wordpress site and I want to use the plugin's shortcode to add items into the cart. I don't know how to call a shorcode in a page. The short code is supposed to generate a button that allows the user to add items into the cart. However it is not adding into the cart. Please help me. My code is here. Please help. `[add_to_cart item="EX-29"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out to use the `do_shortcode` inbuilt function. For example I used `echo do_shortcode("[add_to_cart item=\"EX-29]\"");` and it worked.